# Expo File System pauseAsync gives error 'No download object available'

Tags: react-native, expo

I am using the expo-file-system to create a resumable download. I am using the same example as in the expo documentation.

https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem/

The download part is working good. It downloads the file and gives progress along the way. But when I try to us the pauseAsync function it gives the error.

'No download object available'

```
export default function App() {
const [downloadProgress,setDownloadProgress] = useState({})

const callback = downloadProgress => {
const progress = downloadProgress.totalBytesWritten / downloadProgress.totalBytesExpectedToWrite;
console.log(progress);
setDownloadProgress(progress)
};

const downloadResumable = FileSystem.createDownloadResumable(
'http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4',
FileSystem.documentDirectory + 'small.mp4',
{},
callback
);

startDownload = async() =>{

try {
  const { uri } = await downloadResumable.downloadAsync();
  console.log('Finished downloading to ', uri);
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e);
}
}

pauseDownload = async() =>{
try {
  await downloadResumable.pauseAsync();
  console.log('Paused download operation, saving for future retrieval');
  AsyncStorage.setItem('pausedDownload', JSON.stringify(downloadResumable.savable()));
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e);
}
}


return (
<View style={{    flex: 1,backgroundColor: '#fff',alignItems: 'center',justifyContent: 'center',marginTop: 20}}>
  <TouchableNativeFeedback onPress = {this.startDownload}>
    <View style={{alignItems:'center',justifyContent:'center',height:50,width:100,backgroundColor:'#00f',marginBottom:2}}>
      <Text style={{color:'#fff'}}>Download</Text>
    </View>
  </TouchableNativeFeedback>

  <TouchableNativeFeedback onPress = {this.pauseDownload}>
    <View style={{alignItems:'center',justifyContent:'center',height:50,width:100,backgroundColor:'#00f',marginBottom:2}}>
      <Text style={{color:'#fff'}}>Pause</Text>
    </View>
  </TouchableNativeFeedback>
</View>
);
}
```

This is the error that I'm getting. [Error image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGy1O.png)

Comment: Hey @Rafay Saleem,
did you fix this problem ? I have the same error and cant figure out the issue. Can you help here please ?

Comment: I used this package instead. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-background-downloader

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is just that you didn't ues useRef hook to save your resumableDownload object. So I think that your object is dismissed. becuase of that you are getting NO DOWNLOAD AVAILABLE error. useRef helped me and pauseAsync worked for me correctly.

```
//creating downloadResumable.
    const resumableDownload = useRef(FileSystem.createDownloadResumable(
        'http://d23dyxeqlo5psv.cloudfront.net/big_buck_bunny.mp4',
        FileSystem.documentDirectory + 'small.mp4',
        {},
        callback,
      ));

  //pausing donwload

  const pauseDownload = async () => {
    try {
     await resumableDownload.current.pauseAsync();
       
        console.log('Paused download operation, saving for future retrieval');
        AsyncStorage.setItem('pausedDownload', JSON.stringify(resumableDownload.current.savable()));
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
      }
}
```